# Get actual value specified in CSS using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

### Explanation

*I cannot believe this has not been asked before but anyway... Please do **not** get confused with this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6732982/how-to-get-actual-css-value-with-jquery).*

I am trying to store the height of an element using the jQuery `data` method so that I can retrieve this value and reset the original value on a specific element.

However, when I try to get the height of my element, it returns the computed height and not the actual CSS value. Whilst this is extremely helpful in other cases, I actually need to get the exact value specified in my stylesheet whether it be 100%, auto, 10px etc...

### My Question

Is there a way to get the exact CSS (non-computed) value of an element using jQuery?

For example (CSS):

```
#wrapper {
    height: auto;
}
```

And JS:

```
// Returns 'auto' NOT computed value...
var height = $('#wrapper').height();
```

### Further Information

The only alternative I can currently see is just removing the inline `style` tag on my element which will remove any styles applied by jQuery. The obviously flaw in this method is that it will remove all styles not just one in particular...

Comment: YOu can't get it.  (Only after DOM loaded and computed values)

Comment: No, You can not access original style data, only the computed styles

Comment: @LimH. Did you read the question?

Comment: @FlorianMargaine Sorry

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get a style attribute from a css class by javascript/jquery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16965515/how-to-get-a-style-attribute-from-a-css-class-by-javascript-jquery) - which has a [working answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16965515/how-to-get-a-style-attribute-from-a-css-class-by-javascript-jquery/16966533#16966533)

Comment: Completely depending on the page structure [**this demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/zETzr/) uses `console.log(document.styleSheets[1].rules[0].cssText);` to output the whole rule. But you would have to iterate the `document.styleSheets` and `rules` arrays yourself and parse the result. Might work for simple rules.

Comment: @BenCarey sorry I was being an idiot. I went into jQuery source code and here is the helper function it uses to get style every time: `return elem.ownerDocument.defaultView.getComputedStyle( elem, null );` whether it's `.height()` or `.css()`. So yeah, computed values only. Path to source: `jquery / src / css / var / getStyles.js`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a way to get the exact CSS (non-computed) value of an element using jQuery?

You can only retrieve the computed value in `px` via the DOM.

That being said, you can work out the percentage by getting the elements height and comparing it to the parent's height. `em`, `en` and other measurements are not possible.

Comment: This is wrong. You can get it by parsing the CSS file. Not something I'd recommend, but it's doable.

Comment: @FlorianMargaine true. I added the `via the DOM` caveat to my answer. If you want to write a CSS parser in Javascript, you're a braver man than I ;)

Comment: The DOM provides access to all the CSS through `document.stylesheets`. That said, a CSS parser is not something hard to write. I wouldn't recommend because it usually means something else is wrong.

Comment: Feel free to answer the question. I'm not being facetious, I'd be interested to see how it's done as I've never seen it myself.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I thought so, how irritating! Thank you anyway :-) +1

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan see the comments on the question :)

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I have posted the link to the dupe question where I provide a working answer.

Answer (score 10):

Using jQuery you can only get the calculated value.

As an alternative, I have written a script to find the original css value by enumerating the stylesheets applied to the page, matching the selector and weighing it up by precedence and CSS specificity.

This is handy for finding out if something is `auto` vs. `100%` vs. fixed size.

usage :

```
resolveAppliedStyle(document.getElementById("wrapper"), "height");
```

You can get the script for resolveAppliedStyle from :

https://github.com/stephen-james/FixedHeaderTable/blob/master/dependencies/lib/resolveAppliedStyle.js

and the script it uses to calculate specificity from :

https://github.com/keeganstreet/specificity/blob/master/specificity.js