# jQuery/JS – Get font-size in unit set in CSS (vw units)

Tags: jquery, css, viewport-units

I've set my font sizes using vw but want to retrieve this value in jQuery but when I use `$('.textarea').css('font-size');` it returns the `px` equivalent rather than the `vw` unit.

Is there any way for it to return the correct stated value?

Comment: Yes, divide it with window width, than multiply by 100 :)

Comment: Thanks! Or I guess I could use `$('.textarea')[0].style.fontSize;`?

Comment: @JohnthePainter that will return "" in some browsers see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15195209/how-to-get-font-size-in-html  even that will get you pixels. Calculate it like skobaljic suggested

Comment: `You can only retrieve the computed value in px via the DOM`, as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19404747/get-actual-value-specified-in-css-using-jquery#19404773). (Voted to close, as duplicate)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you have value in px, multiply it by `100/($(window).width())`

For example(in your case):

```
$('.textarea').css('font-size')*(100/($(window).width()))
```

Please let me know, if it works

Answer (score 0):

When using jQuery .css('font-size'), the value returned will always be the computed font size in pixels instead of the value used (vw, em, %, etc). You will need to convert this number into your desired value.

*(The following uses a font size of 24px and a window width of 1920px as an example)*

To convert the px into vw, first convert the computed font size into a number.

```
// e.g. converts '24px' into '24'
fontSize = parseFloat($('.textarea').css('font-size'));
```

Next, multiply this number by 99.114 divided by the window width.
(Usually when converting px to vw, you would divide 100 by the window width, however I find the results are slightly incorrect when converting for font sizes).

```
// returns 1.2389249999999998
fontSize = fontSize * (99.114 / $(window).width());
```

You can optionally clean up the large decimal returned by rounding to the nearest 100th decimal place.

```
// returns 1.24
fontSize.toFixed(2)
```

And now you have the final number you need, just manually add 'vw' where desired.

```
// returns 1.24vw
fontSize = fontSize + 'vw';
```

Of course, you can put this all together if you want to shorten your code

```
// returns 1.24vw
newFontSize = (parseFloat($('.textarea').css('font-size'))*(99.114/ $(window).width())).toFixed(2) + 'vw';
```