# jQuery $(e).css('font-size')) get font-size value in percentages

Tags: javascript, jquery

When using `$(e).css('font-size'))` how to get the font-size as it(100% in my example)?
Its return it as 100% of 16px = 16px.

```js
jQuery
(
  function($)
  {   
    alert($('div').css('font-size'));//16px, but need get 100%
  }
);
```

```css
body
{
  font-size: 16px
}
div
{
  font-size: 100%
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <div>font size here is 100%</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get a style attribute from a CSS class by javascript/jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16965515/how-to-get-a-style-attribute-from-a-css-class-by-javascript-jquery)

Comment: See also [jQuery/JS – Get font-size in unit set in CSS (vw units)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45824626/215552) (which was marked as a dupe of the same target)

Comment: @somethinghere window.getComputedStyle( e ).getPropertyValue( 'font-size' ) also return in px

Comment: @HereticMonkey no

Comment: This question differs from [jQuery/JS – Get font-size in unit set in CSS (vw units)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45824626/215552) only in the symbol used is `vw` instead of `%`. The answer is the same; Calculate it yourself. Get the size in `px`, divide by the size in `px' set in `body`, multiply by 100. Now you have it expressed as a percentage.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't take it out directly, you will have to calculate it manually.

```
var fontSizePercentage =((parseFloat($('div p').css('font-size')) / parseFloat($("body").css('font-size'))) * 100).toFixed(2);
```

alert(fontSizePercentage);

Comment: Note that it might be better if you just [edit] your answer, click the "Copy snippet to answer" button, and add your code to that. Then we could see the answer in context...

Comment: Ok. In this method, better make hierarchical search to closest parent width fixed font size instead of use body font size.